# Convert multiple CSS files to SASS / SCSS

Tags: css, sass, gulp, compass-sass

I am creating a website using Drupal 8 and I found a free theme online which I have installed on my site.  The theme consists of multiple folders of CSS files. I would like to use SASS to extend and modify this theme.  If I want to do this, is it as simple as renaming all the files to SCSS files and compile using Gulp or Compass? Or is there a better practice to follow? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: css files are valid scss files

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to make any kind of conversion.

You can just change the file extension if you need to.

> The SCSS syntax uses the file extension .scss. With a few small
>   exceptions, it’s a superset of CSS, which means essentially all valid
>   CSS is valid SCSS as well. Because of its similarity to CSS, it’s the
>   easiest syntax to get used to and the most popular.

From https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax